# How can i replace keyboard events with touch screen events?

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I have some events and i want change them on touch events when i use phone or something with sensor display

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  moveCheck(oldLocation);

  switch (e.key) {
    case 'ArrowLeft':
      shift('left');
      break;

    case 'ArrowRight':
      shift('right');
      break;

    case 'ArrowUp':
      vertikalShift('up');
      break;

    case 'ArrowDown':
      vertikalShift('down');
      break;
  }

  saveTable();

  moveCheck(newLocation);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (startButton.matches('.start')) {
    return;
  }

  if (oldLocation.join() === newLocation.join()) {
    return;
  }

  scoreInfo.textContent = score;

  addCell(playObject);
  saveTable();
  winOrLose(playObject);
});
```

maybe I can add some condition that when I use a phone or just a smaller screen I start reacting to touch events instead of keyboard ones

Comment: Just add listeners for touch events keeping the existing keyboard event listener(s) and refactor your code to use both no need to pick one or the other.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events